# jupyter labを使用したい

Tags: vscode, windows-10, anaconda, jupyter-lab

anacondaをインストールし、jupyter labを起動したい。
(vs codeもインストール済み)
Windowsなのでコマンドプロンプトでjupyter labと入力してenter
すると、

'jupyter' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。

となってしまう。

Comment: 何故コマンドプロンプトとVSCodeが出てくるのでしょう？ スタートメニューにJupyter Notebookが登録されていると思われますが、`jupyter-notebook-script.py`というスクリプトを(作業フォルダ？をパラメータ指定して)起動していて、それと名前が類似の`jupyter-lab-script.py`というのがあるので、そちらが使えるのかもしれません。あるいはVSCodeで使いたいなら、まずVSCodeを起動してそこから使うことになのでは？ [...MicrosoftからJupyter 拡張機能が提供されたので...](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/mrmo-vscode-jupyter-20201112/), [VSCodeでの...](https://qiita.com/SolKul/items/f078877acd23bb1ea5b5), [\[小ネタ\] VS Code Python拡張機能...](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/mrmo-vscode-jupyter-anacondanavigator-20201120/) やりたいことの前提や状況などをもう少し詳細化して質問を編集してみてください。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/331274 と同じ質問でしょうか？

Comment: あるいはマルチポスト先でコメントされているように、コマンドプロンプトはコマンドプロンプトでも、Windowsのコマンドプロンプトではなく、スタートメニューからAnacondaのコマンドプロンプト`Anaconda Powershell Prompt (anaconda3)`とか`Anaconda Prompt (anaconda3)`ならば`jupyter lab`のコマンド入力で jupyter lab が起動します。だからコマンドプロンプト違いでしょうね。で、その時にはVSCodeは絡まないはずです。

Answer (score 1):

Windows で jupyter lab をインストールする手順

### Anaconda （Python のパッケージ管理ソフト） をインストール

https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual
のページの 下にある
Windows
「64-Bit Graphical Installer」
「32-Bit Graphical Installer」
のどちらかを選んでダウンロードしてインストールします。
※ OS が 64ビット か 32ビットかに合わせて選択します。

### Jupyter lab の起動

インストールが完了すると、
スタートメニューに `Anaconda3` フォルダができその中に
`Anaconda Navigator` が追加されています。

それをクリックして 表示されるメニューの中から「Jupyter Lab」をクリックすると

`Jupyter Lab` が起動できます。

### Visual Studio Code の Jupyter Extention インストール方法

質問者が Visual Studio Code を気にしているので‥追記します。
Visual Studio Code の中から Jupyter Notebook を使いたいのであれば
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support
にあるように
Visual Studio Code の エクステンション（拡張機能）として
[Python extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)
[Jupyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter)

を入れると `.ipynb` ファイルを実行＆編集できるようになります。